# codename one web services soap call not working

Tags: java, web-services, soap, codenameone

I want to consume SOAP based web services when click on a login button.
My code is as follows

```
loginButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        Log.p(" CaterId : "+catererId.getText());
        Log.p(" Username : "+loginId.getText());
        Log.p(" Password : "+password.getText());

        final String InputParameter = "<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap=\"http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">" 
                                       +"   <soap:Header/>" 
                                       +"   <soap:Body>" 
                                       +"      <tem:AuthenticateSupervisor>" 
                                       +"         <tem:username>TestAbhi</tem:username>" 
                                       +"         <tem:password>TestAbhi</tem:password>" 
                                       +"         <tem:caterer>calihanint</tem:caterer>" 
                                       +"      </tem:AuthenticateSupervisor>" 
                                       +"   </soap:Body>" 
                                       +"</soap:Envelope>";
        ConnectionRequest r= new ConnectionRequest() {

            @Override
            protected void buildRequestBody(OutputStream os) throws IOException {
                os.write(InputParameter.getBytes("UTF-8"));
            }

            @Override
            protected void postResponse() {
                //super.postResponse();
            }

            @Override
            protected void readResponse(InputStream input) throws IOException {
                //super.readResponse(input);
                XMLParser parser = new XMLParser();
                Element elem = parser.parse(new InputStreamReader(input));
                Log.p(" Came heer"+elem);
            }                
        };
        r.setUrl("http://192.168.10.224:8888/CXPPostScheduleService/Service.asmx");
        r.setPost(false);
        /*r.addArgument("username", "TestAbhi");
        r.addArgument("password", "TestAbhi");
        r.addArgument("caterer", "calihanint");*/
        r.setContentType("application/soap+xml;charset=UTF-8");
        NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(r);
        r.getResponseData();
    }
});
```

It displays an html file as response. Could you please assist me to check what I'm doing wrong in this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you need a post request try:

```
r.setPost(true);
```

If you are calling this from the device make sure the device is in the same network as the server otherwise the NAT local address will be unreachable. Notice that this will also apply to the simulator if the server is hosted elsewhere and not on your machine.

I also suggest checking the server logs, the error response code and post the error HTML. You can use the network monitor tool in the simulator to further debug this.

Comment: Added a few additional options